# Bokeh CustomJS callback using slider - Map - patches

Tags: javascript, python, callback, slider, bokeh

I am trying to update a map based on the slider value but when I run the code no plot is created. My code is shown below:

```
# Creating the Slider

slider = Slider(title = 'Day', 
                start = np.min(covidmap['day_of_year']), end = np.max(covidmap['day_of_year']), 
                step = 1, value = np.min(covidmap['day_of_year']))
# This callback triggers the filter when the slider changes
callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source=geosource), 
                    code = """source.change.emit();""")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
# Creates custom filter that selects the rows of the month based on the value in the slider
custom_filter = CustomJSFilter(args = dict(slider = slider, 
                                           source = geosource), 
                               code = """
var data = source.data;
                var f = slider.value;
                var indices = [];
                x = data['day_of_year']
                cumsum = data['cumsum']
for (var i = 0; i < source.get_length(); i++){
 if (x[i] == f){
 indices.push(true);
 } else {
 indices.push(false);
 }
}
return indices;
""")
# Uses custom_filter to determine which set of sites are visible
view1 = CDSView(source = geosource, filters = [custom_filter])



#Define a sequential multi-hue color palette.
palette = brewer['YlGnBu'][8]
#Reverse color order so that dark blue is highest obesity.
palette = palette[::-1]
#Instantiate LinearColorMapper that linearly maps numbers in a range, into a sequence of colors. Input nan_color.
color_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 100000, nan_color = '#d9d9d9')
#Create color bar. 
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=8,width = 500, height = 20,
                     border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), orientation = 'horizontal')
#Create figure object.
p = figure(plot_height = 600 , 
           plot_width = 950, 
          x_range=(2000000,5500000), y_range=(2500000,5500000))
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

# Adding map tile
p.add_tile(tile_provider)

#Add patch renderer to figure. 
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,fill_color = {'field' :'cumsum', 'transform' : color_mapper},
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1, view=view1)
#Specify layout
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')

# Make a column layout of widgetbox(slider) and plot, and add it to the current document
layout = column(p,slider)
#Display plot inline in Jupyter notebook
output_notebook()
#Display plot
show(layout)
```

FYI. Before running the above code I merged the shape dataset with the dataset the contains the information and now the dataset looks as shown below.

cases   deaths   cumsum   num_days  CNTRY_NAME  geometry    day_of_year

0   2.0 0.0 2.0 1   Albania POLYGON ((2314546.339 4928852.306, 2314022.746...   69

1   4.0 0.0 6.0 2   Albania POLYGON ((2314546.339 4928852.306, 2314022.746...   70

2   4.0 0.0 10.0    3   Albania POLYGON ((2314546.339 4928852.306, 2314022.746...   71

3   1.0 1.0 11.0    4   Albania POLYGON ((2314546.339 4928852.306, 2314022.746...   72

After that I used the below code to convert it to GeoJSONDataSource which is what I used to plot the map

```
#Read data to json.
merged_json = json.loads(covidmap.to_json())
#Convert to String like object.
json_data = json.dumps(merged_json)

#Input GeoJSON source that contains features for plotting.
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

In GeoJSONDataSource there is no 'data' parameter, you have 'geojson' which is string, not dictionary. CustomJS gives you access to source.geojson which will have to be converted to into something usable in Javascript.